# Javascript Counting Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, count

I am been having trouble counting the number of objects in this array in server-side javascript.

Below is a JSON object which was parsed out using the array that I am trying to count.

NOTE:  The object is in object form, not JSON string form.

JSON Object:

```
[{"dataSymbol":"21135103","isHoliday":false,"isIPO":false,"lastTradeTime":40073.49652777778,"strikePrice":"33.00","last":"1.30","change":"0.20","changePct":"18.1818","lastRaw":1.3,"ask":"1.40","bid":"1.30","lastTime":40073.49652777778,"tick":0,"openInterest":"13.6K","volume":"80311","expDate":40194,"coName":"AJR Jan0 33.0 C"},
 {"dataSymbol":"21339645","isHoliday":false,"isIPO":false,"lastTradeTime":40073.50479166866,"strikePrice":"6.00","last":"2.11","change":"0.01","changePct":"0.4762","lastRaw":2.11,"ask":"2.15","bid":"2.10","lastTime":40073.50479166866,"tick":0,"openInterest":"105.00","volume":"62313","expDate":40285,"coName":"EK Apr0 6.0 C"},
 {"dataSymbol":"13511861","isHoliday":false,"isIPO":false,"lastTradeTime":40073.489583333336,"strikePrice":"113.00","last":"1.41","change":"-6.34","changePct":"-81.8065","lastRaw":1.41,"ask":"7.60","bid":"7.45","lastTime":40073.489583333336,"tick":0,"openInterest":"805.00","volume":"62975","expDate":40138,"coName":"SPY Nov8 113.0 P"},
 {"dataSymbol":"20718334","isHoliday":false,"isIPO":false,"lastTradeTime":40073.49375,"strikePrice":"40.00","last":"1.42","change":"-0.05","changePct":"-3.4014","lastRaw":1.42,"ask":"1.46","bid":"1.44","lastTime":40073.49375,"tick":0,"openInterest":"116.1K","volume":"60470","expDate":40194,"coName":"QQQQ Jan0 40.0 P"},
 {"dataSymbol":"20348966","isHoliday":false,"isIPO":false,"lastTradeTime":40073.47708333333,"strikePrice":"41.00","last":"2.39","change":"-0.06","changePct":"-2.449","lastRaw":2.39,"ask":"2.45","bid":"2.42","lastTime":40073.47708333333,"tick":-1,"openInterest":"4.6K","volume":"60320","expDate":40257,"coName":"QQQQ Mar0 41.0 P"}]
```

I usually use myObject.length to count this type of array, but that is not working.

```
Response.Write(optionsQuotes.length);
```

The above code is returning a result of 21339646 as the count, when the actual count of the array is 5.

I would rather not have to loop through the array to count it, because I am looping through it later in order to draw a table, and I need to know the last iteration before the table draw begins.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

```
//here is where I am gettnig the array of objects...
var myObj =  common.getMyObj("param1", "param2");
```

I serialized the object for the purpose of showing the contents of the array.

myObj.constructor is an Array.

This is on the server side also BTW.

Comment: Hi, just a hint: Did you see that you have a dataSymbol with the value 21339645 (the value returned by length minus one)? ;)

Comment: Yeah.  It's on the server side as well.  

Good point about the dataSymbol value.

Comment: Wow. It's awesome how SO displayed your question!

Comment: Yeah!  that is awesome.  agreed

Comment: @idrumgood javascript can run on the server-side (see node.js for instance)

Comment: @user1524316 Jeez dude, that was 4.5 years ago. Who knew about node.js then?!

Comment: In classic asp, you can code in VB Script or JScript.   That's what I was using here.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ECMAScript doesn't handle the length of "assocative" arrays like PHP does - either use a real list that has a .length property, set the .length property manually in the JSON as you populate properties in the object, or do a for..in loop and make sure to use .hasOwnProperty and increment some counter.

Comment: not relevant as Shane wants to determine the length of the enclosing array

Comment: I looped through the array and iterated my counter, which worked.

Comment: What are you using to evaluate it?

Comment: On the server side, this is just an array of objects.  I am not evaluating it, since it's an actual array, not a JSON string.  

I ended up using your example, and i asked my boss and he indicated that you are correct.  You cannot use .length on an associative array in JScript.  

Thanks

Comment: @Shane: The array in your question isn't an associative array. There is no such thing as associative arrays in javascript. There are arrays and there are objects.

Comment: How is this marked as the right answer? The question does not show an associative array (Object), it shows a numeric Array.

Answer (score 2):

Mhh... maybe is not a JSON object but an string and the length that is returning is the length of the string and not of the json array

With prototype you need to do something like

```
var data = '{ "name": "Violet", "occupation": "character" }'.evalJSON();
data.length
```

but this obviously is depending of the framework that you are using.

Comment: the JSON string was just to demonstrate the contents of the object that I am attempting to count.  It is an actual object within the code

Answer (score 0):

The bug must be somewhere else as the following

```
<script>
var foo = eval('[{"dataSymbol":"21135103","isHoliday":false,"isIPO":false,"lastTradeTime":40073.49652777778,"strikePrice":"33.00","last":"1.30","change":"0.20","changePct":"18.1818","lastRaw":1.3,"ask":"1.40","bid":"1.30","lastTime":40073.49652777778,"tick":0,"openInterest":"13.6K","volume":"80311","expDate":40194,"coName":"AJR Jan0 33.0 C"},{"dataSymbol":"21339645","isHoliday":false,"isIPO":false,"lastTradeTime":40073.50479166866,"strikePrice":"6.00","last":"2.11","change":"0.01","changePct":"0.4762","lastRaw":2.11,"ask":"2.15","bid":"2.10","lastTime":40073.50479166866,"tick":0,"openInterest":"105.00","volume":"62313","expDate":40285,"coName":"EK Apr0 6.0 C"},{"dataSymbol":"13511861","isHoliday":false,"isIPO":false,"lastTradeTime":40073.489583333336,"strikePrice":"113.00","last":"1.41","change":"-6.34","changePct":"-81.8065","lastRaw":1.41,"ask":"7.60","bid":"7.45","lastTime":40073.489583333336,"tick":0,"openInterest":"805.00","volume":"62975","expDate":40138,"coName":"SPY Nov8 113.0 P"},{"dataSymbol":"20718334","isHoliday":false,"isIPO":false,"lastTradeTime":40073.49375,"strikePrice":"40.00","last":"1.42","change":"-0.05","changePct":"-3.4014","lastRaw":1.42,"ask":"1.46","bid":"1.44","lastTime":40073.49375,"tick":0,"openInterest":"116.1K","volume":"60470","expDate":40194,"coName":"QQQQ Jan0 40.0 P"},{"dataSymbol":"20348966","isHoliday":false,"isIPO":false,"lastTradeTime":40073.47708333333,"strikePrice":"41.00","last":"2.39","change":"-0.06","changePct":"-2.449","lastRaw":2.39,"ask":"2.45","bid":"2.42","lastTime":40073.47708333333,"tick":-1,"openInterest":"4.6K","volume":"60320","expDate":40257,"coName":"QQQQ Mar0 41.0 P"}]');
document.writeln(foo.length);
</script>
```

yields the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to `eval` the string.  Could 21339645 be the number of characters?