# Counting array in JSON object javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439969/javascript-counting-array-of-objects), I did not found the answer of how to count the array in this JSON object.

```
[{"dataSymbol":"21135103","isHoliday":false,"isIPO":false,"lastTradeTime":40073.49652777778,"strikePrice":"33.00","last":"1.30","change":"0.20","changePct":"18.1818","lastRaw":1.3,"ask":"1.40","bid":"1.30","lastTime":40073.49652777778,"tick":0,"openInterest":"13.6K","volume":"80311","expDate":40194,"coName":"AJR Jan0 33.0 C"},
 {"dataSymbol":"21339645","isHoliday":false,"isIPO":false,"lastTradeTime":40073.50479166866,"strikePrice":"6.00","last":"2.11","change":"0.01","changePct":"0.4762","lastRaw":2.11,"ask":"2.15","bid":"2.10","lastTime":40073.50479166866,"tick":0,"openInterest":"105.00","volume":"62313","expDate":40285,"coName":"EK Apr0 6.0 C"},
 {"dataSymbol":"13511861","isHoliday":false,"isIPO":false,"lastTradeTime":40073.489583333336,"strikePrice":"113.00","last":"1.41","change":"-6.34","changePct":"-81.8065","lastRaw":1.41,"ask":"7.60","bid":"7.45","lastTime":40073.489583333336,"tick":0,"openInterest":"805.00","volume":"62975","expDate":40138,"coName":"SPY Nov8 113.0 P"},
 {"dataSymbol":"20718334","isHoliday":false,"isIPO":false,"lastTradeTime":40073.49375,"strikePrice":"40.00","last":"1.42","change":"-0.05","changePct":"-3.4014","lastRaw":1.42,"ask":"1.46","bid":"1.44","lastTime":40073.49375,"tick":0,"openInterest":"116.1K","volume":"60470","expDate":40194,"coName":"QQQQ Jan0 40.0 P"}]
```

In this example the result should be 4.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: isn't it just `.length`??

Comment: How could we use `.length` without object name :/

Answer (score 1):

Use [Array.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length).

```
[{"dataSymbol":"21135103","isHoliday":false,"isIPO":false,"lastTradeTime":40073.49652777778,"strikePrice":"33.00","last":"1.30","change":"0.20","changePct":"18.1818","lastRaw":1.3,"ask":"1.40","bid":"1.30","lastTime":40073.49652777778,"tick":0,"openInterest":"13.6K","volume":"80311","expDate":40194,"coName":"AJR Jan0 33.0 C"},
 {"dataSymbol":"21339645","isHoliday":false,"isIPO":false,"lastTradeTime":40073.50479166866,"strikePrice":"6.00","last":"2.11","change":"0.01","changePct":"0.4762","lastRaw":2.11,"ask":"2.15","bid":"2.10","lastTime":40073.50479166866,"tick":0,"openInterest":"105.00","volume":"62313","expDate":40285,"coName":"EK Apr0 6.0 C"},
 {"dataSymbol":"13511861","isHoliday":false,"isIPO":false,"lastTradeTime":40073.489583333336,"strikePrice":"113.00","last":"1.41","change":"-6.34","changePct":"-81.8065","lastRaw":1.41,"ask":"7.60","bid":"7.45","lastTime":40073.489583333336,"tick":0,"openInterest":"805.00","volume":"62975","expDate":40138,"coName":"SPY Nov8 113.0 P"},
 {"dataSymbol":"20718334","isHoliday":false,"isIPO":false,"lastTradeTime":40073.49375,"strikePrice":"40.00","last":"1.42","change":"-0.05","changePct":"-3.4014","lastRaw":1.42,"ask":"1.46","bid":"1.44","lastTime":40073.49375,"tick":0,"openInterest":"116.1K","volume":"60470","expDate":40194,"coName":"QQQQ Jan0 40.0 P"}]
.length
```

Comment: Ooops! Use like this in the code?

Comment: `var x = [{"dataSymbol": ..... }];` and then use `x.length` everywhere

Comment: Yep, that should be all you need.

Comment: If you found this answer useful, please mark it as correct for the benefit of future users.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) property

```
   var  data =[{"dataSymbol":"21135103","isHoliday":false,"isIPO":false,"lastTradeTime":40073.49652777778,"strikePrice":"33.00","last":"1.30","change":"0.20","changePct":"18.1818","lastRaw":1.3,"ask":"1.40","bid":"1.30","lastTime":40073.49652777778,"tick":0,"openInterest":"13.6K","volume":"80311","expDate":40194,"coName":"AJR Jan0 33.0 C"},
         {"dataSymbol":"21339645","isHoliday":false,"isIPO":false,"lastTradeTime":40073.50479166866,"strikePrice":"6.00","last":"2.11","change":"0.01","changePct":"0.4762","lastRaw":2.11,"ask":"2.15","bid":"2.10","lastTime":40073.50479166866,"tick":0,"openInterest":"105.00","volume":"62313","expDate":40285,"coName":"EK Apr0 6.0 C"},
         {"dataSymbol":"13511861","isHoliday":false,"isIPO":false,"lastTradeTime":40073.489583333336,"strikePrice":"113.00","last":"1.41","change":"-6.34","changePct":"-81.8065","lastRaw":1.41,"ask":"7.60","bid":"7.45","lastTime":40073.489583333336,"tick":0,"openInterest":"805.00","volume":"62975","expDate":40138,"coName":"SPY Nov8 113.0 P"},
         {"dataSymbol":"20718334","isHoliday":false,"isIPO":false,"lastTradeTime":40073.49375,"strikePrice":"40.00","last":"1.42","change":"-0.05","changePct":"-3.4014","lastRaw":1.42,"ask":"1.46","bid":"1.44","lastTime":40073.49375,"tick":0,"openInterest":"116.1K","volume":"60470","expDate":40194,"coName":"QQQQ Jan0 40.0 P"}]

        alert(data.length);
```

[JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HTHtV/)